# RemoteFX on Remote Desktop Session Host not working

Tags: remote-desktop-services, rds, remote-desktop

I have configured Remote FX on our Windows 2008 R2 SP1 Remote Desktop Session Host by following this guide:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817595%28WS.10%29.aspx 
However, when I connect via my Windows 7 SP1 client to the server and I verify the eventlog (where event 1000 and 1001 should appear) there are no events. 
 I used this info to verify the events: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817580%28WS.10%29.aspx

Trying to watch multimedia on the RDSH server is still very choppy.

Is there anything I'm missing or something else I could check to get this to work?

Comment: What hardware do you ahve for the graphics card? What drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while testing RemoteFX today, and it was a problem with the Remote Desktop Connection settings. Ensure these two things are done within the RDC (mstsc.exe) on the client:

- On the "Display" tab, have 32 bit colour checked
- On the "Experience" tab, have LAN (10 Mbps or higher) set